# Cannot run PlaidML: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, h5py, plaidml

I am trying to run Keras with my GPU on my Macbook Pro (2020).
tried to run a test with plaidml

```
$ plaidbench keras mobilenet
```

I get the following error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
Set --print-stacktraces to see the entire traceback
```

I read to install h5py==2.10.0
However, this fails since it's not able to build a wheel for h5py==2.10.0

These are my installed packaged:

```
keras==2.2.4
tensorflow==2.5.3
pyopencl==2021.2.13
plaidml-keras==0.7.0
plaidbench==0.7.0
```

Python version (installed via virtualenv): 3.9.7

Please help!!

:)

Comment: Something, somewhere is expecting a `bytes` object but is getting a `str`. I can't tell where from this. Perhaps use the `--print-stacktraces` as it suggests?

Comment: No it's a problem of h5py version. However, when I downgrade it to 2.10.0 is fails to build the wheel.

Comment: It may be a version problem, but it's a version causing something to get a `str` when it expects a `bytes`. Keith's description of the problem is unambiguously correct. (`.decode()` is what one calls to convert `bytes` to `str`).

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the problem by editing keras' code...

Access your '`site-packages`' directory ... to open up '`saving.py`'

i.e. `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py`

Then go to line 1004 and 1008 to comment out `.decode('utf-8')` parts of the code.